# How to declare a type in TypeScript that only includes objects and not functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

Is it in TypeScript somehow possible to define a type so that it only includes objects but not functions?

Example:

```
type T = { [name: string]: any } // How to modify this to only accepts objects???

const t: T = () => {} // <- This should not work after modification
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I perfectly understand your question, but just to play devil's advocate here, what would be wrong with someone passing in a function if it contained all the properties you expected it to have?

Comment: It's about overloading a function with arity 1: First signature for an object argument, second signature for a function argument. In my code the compiler took always the first signature (for objects and for functions), that resulted in not intended type inference. The solution in my particular case was to change the order of the signature declarations. Hope it's clear what I mean. Means: My problem is solved, nevertheless I'm still interested in the answer of my above question ... BTW: Something like Exclude<T, Function> seems also not to work...

Comment: That makes sense. As far as I know, it requires a runtime check to differentiate between a function and a plain object since in JavaScript a function *is* an object. I believe the `Exclude` doesn't work because the assignment widens the function's type to `T` before performing the assertion that it doesn't extend `Function`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no perfect way to refer to a type like "an object which is not a function", since that would require true [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183), and that doesn't exist in TypeScript (as of 3.1 at least).

One easy-enough workaround is to look at the [`Function` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L272-L304) and describe something which is definitely *not* a `Function`, but which would match most non-function objects you're likely to run into.  Example:

```
type NotAFunction = { [k: string]: unknown } & ({ bind?: never } | { call?: never });
```

That means "an object with some unspecified keys, which is either missing a `bind` property or a `call` property".  Let's see how it behaves:

```
const okayObject: NotAFunction = { a: "hey", b: 2, c: true };
const notOkayObject: NotAFunction = () => {}; // error, call is not undefined
```

Good.

The reason that this is a workaround and not a straightforward solution is that some non-functions might have both a `call` and a `bind` property, just by coincidence, and you'll get an undesirable error:

```
const surprisinglyNotOkay: NotAFunction = { 
  publication: "magazine", 
  bind: "staples",
  call: "867-5309",
  fax: null
}; // error, call is not undefined
```

If you really need to support such objects you can change `NotAFunction` to be more complicated and exclude fewer non-functions, but there will likely always be something the definition gets wrong.  It's up to you [how far you want to go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns).

Comment: LOL that link is great