# Typescript: Define type as any but function

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type that allows any type except a function, how can I achieve that?

I tried an intersection like this:

```
type anyButFunction = any | Function;
```

but when I try

```
const foo: anyButFunction = () => null;
```

it does compile fine. How could I create such a type? Is that even possible?

Comment: Doesn't `any | Function` mean "`any` *or* `Function`"?

Comment: Also related to [How to declare a type in TypeScript that only includes objects and not functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692606/how-to-declare-a-type-in-typescript-that-only-includes-objects-and-not-functions/52694022#52694022)

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not possible, it will become possible when negated type become available. The [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) here described this exact use case:

> > Can this be used as a way to restrict the potential type of unbounded types? For example, `number & not 0` to allow any number except the literal 0.
>
> Yep. That's a primary driver for 'em.

If you are looking to restrict the parameter to a function, we can do this currently with generics and conditional types, this will act mostly as a negated type:

```
function noFunctions<T>(p: Exclude<T, Function>) {

}

noFunctions(1) //ok
noFunctions(() => {}) ///error
```

Comment: There's also something like `{apply?: never;}` which is narrower than "not a function" (and could possibly conflict with particular use cases) but does a decent job in its stead without needing generics.

Comment: @jcalz Ah yes I forgot about that option, have used it myself on occasion, but it will force an object type, primitives will not work anymore. But it's a good option to have in the toolkit 10x for posting it :)

Comment: @jcalz clever, but for a new person working on the code such a definition might be not obvious at all. `Exclude<T, Function>` is more "intuitive" unless you leave a comment.

Comment: @kirilloid you can give it a documenting name like `NotFunction = {apply?: never;}` But yes it's not terribly obvious.