# How to safely call a function in typescript that was passed as a parameter of `Type | (() => Type)`

Tags: typescript

I want to pass a parameter to a function that is either a value of Type or a function that returns a value of Type.

For example:

```js
function f<Type>(x: Type | (() => Type)): Type {
  return typeof x === 'function' ? x() : x;
}
```

But typescript complains in this case:

```
This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type '(() => Type) | (Type & Function)' are callable. Type 'Type & Function' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

I was expecting typescript to be intelligent enough to know that x is a function inside of the typeof conditional.

I tried to cast it `return typeof x === 'function' ?  (x as () => Type)() : x;` and this will suppress the error, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this or if there is any downside/catch with this solution?

Comment: What if `Type` is a function type and it takes a required argument? Then `x()` will fail to pass it its argument and bad things can happen. TS doesn't have a perfect way to say "`Type` is not a function" that the compiler will understand, but you could say `Type extends {apply?: never}` (plus other stuff) and the problem goes away. See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W46zeN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hm yes, you are right, Type should never be a function, it should only be possible to pass a function as an initializer exactly like setState does in react.

Comment: So shall I write up an answer?  I'm not missing anything about the question?

Comment: I think this might be one solution to my problem, but it does not technically answer the question. The question explicitly asks for a solution to call the function and not for finding another type to do so. I know that React does it like `useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)):` I really want to find the best practice for this sort of problem and not just a solution that works. It might be that your suggested solution is the way to go, but why for example does React do it differently? One good thing about `S | (() => S)` is that it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: See [ms/TS#37663 - `T | (() => T)` (comment)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663#issuecomment-856961045) — let me know if you'd like for me to write that up as an answer here.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get my point across: the error is *intended*. The compiler catches a safety issue: if `Type` can be a function, then you cannot distinguish between `Type` and `() => Type` based on a `typeof x === 'function'` check, and indeed there could be a runtime error if you try. So the premise of the question is a bit mistaken (TS is being more "intelligent" than you were expecting, not less). You can either not worry about it in which case a type assertion is the correct approach, or you fix the type hole by constraining `Type` to a non-function. How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: React has a problem where if your state is a function, your state will be called by React because it thinks it's `() => S`. Therefore, your state (using `useState`) can never be a function. Now, if you don't care about this, and you properly document it, it shouldn't be a problem to just ignore the compiler. This is not a problem in the implementation of React since React is written in JavaScript and does not have type checking.

Comment: @jcalz I did understand what you wrote and you are right. So for this to work with this type I would need to check for a function without arguments that returns Type and only then call the function. Is this even possible? I guess not, so changing the type is the only option right? Is there a way to constraint the generic to not be a function?

Comment: "Is there a way to constrain the generic to not be a function?" I'm looking at my suggestion and I have `T extends NotAFunction` in there so I'm not sure what you're asking.  In what way did I "change the type"?  All I'm doing is constraining it.  One or both of us is confused here.

Comment: Yep, that was definitely me who got confused :-) Your are correct I guess this is the best way. Regarding the NotAFunction type, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613955/is-there-a-type-in-typescript-for-anything-except-functions is this another solution for a NotAFunction type? Maybe not, but I thought i mention it.

Comment: So, would it be helpful or unhelpful for me to write up an answer at this point?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201173/how-to-safely-call-a-function-in-typescript-that-was-passed-as-a-parameter-of-t/76206997?noredirect=1#comment134395544_76201173) "_your state (using `useState`) can never be a function_": @zenly A state value can be a function, but in order to update it, the functional update form of `setState` must always be used (`() => T` where `T` is the function) — e.g. `setState(() => updatedFunctionValue)`

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I will accept it

Comment: @jsejcksn I was already wondering, good to know that. But I will probably never use a function as a state :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#37663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663) for a full discussion of this issue.

---

In

```
function f<T>(x: T | (() => T)): T {
    return typeof x === 'function' ? x() : x; // error!
    // ----------------------------> ~
    // not callable since T & Function is not callable
}
```

the compiler is warning you about a real type safety issue (although it is fairly unlikely).  The problem is that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` isn't [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) at all.  That means it *might* be a function type itself, and therefore merely checking if `x` is a function isn't sufficient to narrow its type.  And if it turns out that `T` is a function that requires an argument, calling `x()` with no argument could actually be dangerous.  Observe:

```
type G = (x: string) => string;
const g: G = x => x.toUpperCase();
f<G>(g); // works but explodes at runtime
```

Here `g` is a function of type `G` that requires a `string` input.  You are allowed to call `f<G>(g)`, and there's no compiler error there.  But at runtime you end up calling `g()` which dereferences `undefined` and explodes.  So you can't "safely" call `x()` inside the function as written.

Of course this is actually quite unlikely; type inference will cause the compiler to prefer `T` over `() => T` where possible, so calling `f(g)` without manually specifying the type argument as `G` will lead to `T` being inferred as `string` instead of `G`, which is a compiler error:

```
f(g); // error!
//~ <-- type G is not string | () => string
```

So if you're not worried about this happening, the easiest thing to do is use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that:

```
function f<T>(x: T | (() => T)): T {
    return typeof x === 'function' ? (x as () => T)() : x; 
}
```

---

If you *are* worried and want things to be type safe, you could try to constrain `T` so that it must not be a function type.  Unfortunately there's no simple and correct way to say "not a function" as a type.  TypeScript lacks *negated types* (as implemented but never merged in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)), so `T extends not Function` isn't available to us.

One approach which might be close enough is as described in [How to declare a type in TypeScript that only includes objects and not functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52692606/2887218) : write out a type which definitely excludes all functions by prohibiting some property of `Function`s from existing.  Maybe like this:

```
type NotAFunction = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint |
    symbol | { apply?: never; [k: string]: any } // this is an approximation
```

The `NotAFunction` type can be any primitive, and it can also be any object as long as that object doesn't have a defined `apply` member.  This will erroneously exclude non-function objects like `{apply: true}`, but that's probably close enough for most use cases (and if you care you can improve the approximation like `{apply?: never} | {bind?: never}` etc).  Now you can do this:

```
function f<T extends NotAFunction>(x: T | (() => T)): T {
    return typeof x === 'function' ? x() : x;
}
```

And it compiles because the compiler is sure that `typeof x === 'function'` eliminates the `T` possibility.  And now you get a compiler error if you try to call `f<G>(g)`, since `G` is not a `NotAFunction`

```
f<G>(g); // compiler error
```

---

There are other approaches to `T | (()=>T)`, with their pros and cons, and some of these are mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#37663.  I won't go over them here since this answer is long enough already.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkikAzAV2HgBcMB7YUgHgBUA+ACgA8AuJZpAD5J27AJRIAvKz6jRvfgWJKkaCFTJoGVAJ4wItEkk6SJEpAHJylGvXNIA-EbFJenANxIA9J6QQ0aWjQAQkJlIm8kAFpomNi4+ITpAD9QsIjgWiokeBAAG1yQACNc5CgMSmR+ADIkADEKajoGDCgkDKyc-KKS1KQAX3xenT0kAHFJYR4kKCpMYCxxKWnZ8qw3Xvh6GaQsXnGzYyXOADoqWgBVGD00AGEQKAgxdaUSRlGOBY8IgHdAgGtWoUyFkIJwYLlaAATaBIEBZNAUGiQQYvdifLw+PwBYK9bxJJCMaJIYbIcYtNqZZZzHBCZxLGbU-ADfCgSCwBDIACi920tQwxkUxCsjXoTDYXHkgmEdOkzFkksFYVU6k0xN0+kMh1MFmFNmAdkcXFhrRlMmcrg8vWZShJYwmEqpq0W0gZq3WzNZ0DgiDq-IAklAABZ4IbqpAAOUyAEF6tYmhNXfMpcAyGBCn4pYVaLQSiAGEIU-kpRRoSRyhBIZnsOUsgJekooNo0zmpbhYVdctp7LxgBAAG5+DwAbT+vETWAAurw89p+hjiYHyeS8+2YAFOBgwHCmiihQ09WLfJwqBBgJDWpGqDH900OFN+LTTXK5HwQ2EiMqNFp1QYjCYzJYN62A4TjiBaVq7kQtr7JMY4rPMzqOvMzzEJswDbLsdoHJI0gnGclzXHcDxPL0rzvGiohfD4mxgDAGAlGgvj+IEpHsAAREU8BsaIrFtiAvAAIwAEwAMz9JRTKDEAA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use instanceof narrowing instead of typeof.

```
function f<Type>(x: Type | (() => Type)): Type {
  return x instanceof Function ? x() : x;
}
```

a complex version, specify that `Type` shouldn't be a function:

```
type NotFunction<T> = T extends (...args: never[]) => unknown
  ? never
  : T | (() => T);

function f<Type>(x: NotFunction<Type>): Type {
  return typeof x === 'function' ? x() : x;
}

type G = (x: string) => string;
const g: G = (x) => x.toUpperCase();
f<G>(g); // Argument of type 'G' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

f<string>(''); // string
f<string>(() => ''); // string
```

Comment: This does avoid the error but it has the same "problem" as the OP version, in that it's (technically) possible for `Type` to be a function itself and therefore narrowing to `() => Type` is (technically) unsafe, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/we8egW).  Maybe nobody cares because this is unlikely, but it should probably be mentioned in any answer.

Comment: @jcalz You're right. So I added a new version which not allow `Type` to be a function.

Comment: I do like the solution using `instanceof Function` why is it a more elegant way than `(x as () => Type)()`? Why does it work but `typeof`does not?

Comment: [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_realms) is not a reliable heuristic for values created in another execution context.

Comment: @jsejcksn see the complex version, it's using typeof but not instanceof.

Comment: @AndreasRiedmüller Maybe just a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663).